# Weird Flickering Dotted Line on Top of Notebook Screen

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure

I bought a new notebook. Everything works perfectly, except:

In irregular intervals, a flickering, horizontal dotted line appears on the very top of the screen (see picture). Sometimes there is nothing wrong for twenty minutes, then the flickering starts again:

https://streamable.com/pkxdh

I assume this is a hardware problem. Should I send the notebook back?

Thanks for your help. Best regards,
maniacmindhunter

Comment: Does the happen both on mains and battery? Is it.location dependent?

Comment: Happens on mains and battery. I don't know what you mean by location. It certainly doesn't matter where I use the laptop. The problem predominantly occurs when I use tasks in full screen and I have never seen them when doing nothing on the desktop screen - weird. They usually occur when the laptop has got a task to do and is processing.

Comment: From this we can deduce that the problem is likely caused by power draw,and not related to line noise.   I would be inclined to take it back because it seems like there is a failing cap or similar.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me out. Any chance it is caused by drivers though? I use Fedora 29 on an HP laptop with onboard Intel graphics.

Comment: Its conceivable but unlikely.